# Codeigniter active record get rows from two different column value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**properties_tbl**:

```
id   property_type    usd_price euro_price published
----------------------------------------------------
1    private          1000.00    0         yes
2    landed           1200.00    0         yes
3    private                0    1200.00   yes
4    land             2000.00    0         yes
5    land             0          3000.00   yes
6    private          0          1200.00   yes
```

This table is sample table for my website

if usd_price exist euro will 0 and then if euro exist usd price will 0,

I made same exchange value usd and euro price in my system.

My problem is at searching, when I search like these query it show all rows

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`properties_tbl`) 
WHERE (euro >= 100 OR usd >= 110) 
  AND (euro <= 5000 OR usd <= 4500) 
  AND `published` = 'yes'
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? As far as i see your query will return all rows from your sample table.

Comment: try this query: `SELECT *
FROM (`properties_tbl`)
WHERE (euro BETWEEN 100 AND 5000) 
AND (usd BETWEEN 110 AND 4500) 
AND `published` = 'yes'`

Comment: Thank , I m going to try it @devpro

Comment: sure try and share the result.

Comment: Your query is showing the right result as data provided by you. Your every usd or euro is greater then 100 and less then 5000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone , All give me very useful advise.
I created new query base on @devpro and @cfnerd.

```
$this->db->where("(property_price BETWEEN $minprice AND $maxprice OR usd BETWEEN $usd_minprice AND $usd_maxprice)");
```

Now It work!
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is due to your SELECT query, not CodeIgniter's Active Record.  The first condition in your WHERE clause is always true, based on the data in your sample table.  The comment from devpro is correct, in terms of how you should structure the basic query.

To do that in CodeIgniter's Active Record structure, you could likely do it a few different but this works:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('properties_tbl');
$this->db->where('euro BETWEEN 100 AND 5000');
$this->db->where('usd BETWEEN 110 AND 4500');
```

Hope this helps.